# Android Screen recording while display is off

Tags: android

I want to record the screen activity(app UI) or take screenshots of app UI at regular intervals while android display is off. Does anyone know how to do this ?

I have an app which continuously gets data from remote server , based on that data my app does some graph plotting. I want to send these graphs to an embedded device over bluetooth. The embedded device is not smart/powerful enough to do the plotting by itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can record and take screenshots only when device screen is on AND unlocked. what is the purpose of taking screenshot/video of screen turned off...? nothing is drawn, so there is no content to capture, just draw black bitmap or prepare black video then... using `PowerManager` and `KeyguardManager` you can check at any time (e.g. from long-running `Service`) is screen on and is locked (may still be even when screen on)

Comment: I have an app which continuously gets data from remote server , based on that data my app does some graph plotting. I want to send these graphs to an embedded device over bluetooth. The embedded device is not smart/powerful enough to do the plotting by itself.

Comment: and how this is related to screen recording? if you are obtaining data, drawing plots in GUI (`Canvas`, `Paint`, `View`, `onDraw` etc.), then taking screenshot of this and sending further - I must inform you that this is wrong aproach and architecture...

Comment: you should have sticky `Service` which would communicate with server side. when it obtain some data it should prepare a plot `Bitmap` in memory. when its ready then make a decision: if bt-device is connected - send bitmap to it, if gui is visible (screen not locked, app on foreground) - send bitmap to it